# Why is local storage not loading

Tags: javascript

Hello I am trying to do an Assessment where I need to be able to use the Local Storage in JavaScript.
I am very new to this but I cannot get my click counter to save. This is just a simple short game with text nodes but I am trying have a lifetime click counter, what am I doing wrong?
Also sorry if this is messy, this is my first application. This is also my first post so I hope this makes sense

JS

```
const lifetimeClicker = localStorage.getItem('counter')


var button = document.getElementById("counter"),
  count = 0;
  document.getElementById('option-buttons').onclick = function(Counter) {
  count += 1;
  button.innerHTML =  + count;
};

function saveToLocalStorage () {
  localStorage.setItem('lifetimeClicker', counter)
}
document.getElementById('saveButton').onclick = saveToLocalStorage
```

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="textButtons">
    <div id="textSize">Text Size</div>
    <button class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('text').style.fontSize = '1.0em'">S</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('text').style.fontSize = '1.5em'">M</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('text').style.fontSize = '2.0em'">L</button>

    <div class="main">

      <div class="main">

        <h3>Lifetime Clicks</h3>
        <p id="counter">0</p>
        <button id="saveButton">Save</button>
        

        </div>    
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="text">Text</div>
    <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
      <button class="btn" onclick="'clicks = clicks++'">Option 1</button>
      <button class="btn" onclick="'clicks = clicks++'">Option 2</button>
      <button class="btn" onclick="'clicks = clicks++'">Option 3</button>
      <button class="btn" onclick="'clicks = clicks++'">Option 4</button>
      <button class="btn" onclick="'clicks = clicks++'">Option 5</button>

    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

The Option Buttons carryout out the next text and options for the next scene.
At the moment each time I click an option-button it goes to the next textnodes and the counter increments +1[This is what it all looks like together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhA94.png)

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here, you have a button with id `counter`, an `options-button` that increments, and a save button that changes the button innerHTML? Can you provide the HTML and a working example?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an item with the reference of `counter` in Local Storage, but when you are setting it, you set to `lifetimeClicker`. Change the first line of your code to:

```
const lifetimeClicker = localStorage.getItem('lifetimeClicker')
```

Or, inside `saveToLocalStorage`, use `counter` as the first argument of `localStorage.setItem`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
   //We are using the key "current-count" to identify the value we need (you can name this anything)
   //Values in storage must always be strings

const countData = localStorage.getItem("current-count")
const savedData = JSON.parse(countData);    

localStorage.setItem("current-count", JSON.stringify(counter));
```